# how can I fill an curve area with dots? and control it?

Tags: tikz-pgf

[image]
how can I fill an curve area with dots like the blue  picture?

For rectangular area, it is possible as:

```
    ‎\documentclass[tightpage]{standalone}‎
‎\usepackage{varwidth}‎
‎\usepackage{tikz}‎
‎\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,patterns,calc}‎
‎\begin{document}‎
‎\def\yysep{0.42}‎
‎\def\xxsep{7.3}‎
‎\begin{tikzpicture}‎
      ‎\foreach \y in {1,...,4}‎ {%
        ‎\node[inner sep=0pt] (l\y) at (0,\yysep*\y) {};‎
        ‎\node[inner sep=0pt] (r\y) at (\xxsep,\yysep*\y) {};‎
    ‎};‎
       ‎\coordinate (O) at (0,2.5*\yysep);‎
    ‎\draw[dashed] (O)‎ -- +‎+(\xxsep,0);‎
    ‎\begin{pgfonlayer}{background}‎
        ‎\draw[fill=green!20] (l1) rectangle (r4);‎
    ‎\end{pgfonlayer}‎
   ‎\coordinate (auxa) at ($(l1)!0.5!(r1)$);‎
    ‎\coordinate (auxb) at ($(l1)!0.5!(l4)$);‎
    ‎\coordinate (boxcenter) at (auxa |‎- ‎auxb);‎
    ‎\begin{scope}‎
        ‎\pgfsetfillpattern{crosshatch dots}{red}‎
       ‎\fill (l1)‎ -- ‎(boxcenter)‎ -- ‎(r1)‎ -- ‎cycle;‎
        ‎\fill (l4)‎ -- ‎(boxcenter)‎ -- ‎(r4)‎ -- ‎cycle;‎
    ‎\end{scope}‎
    ‎\draw[very thick] (l1) rectangle (r4);‎
‎\end{tikzpicture}‎
‎\end{document}
```

[image]

But for a curve area, How is it  possible?

```
    ‎\documentclass{standalone}‎
‎\usepackage{varwidth}‎
‎\usepackage{tikz}‎
‎\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,patterns,calc}‎
‎\usepackage{xparse}‎
‎\begin{document}‎
‎\begin{tikzpicture}  [scale=2]‎  
‎\filldraw [thick‎, ‎fill=green!20] (120:2cm) arc [start angle = 120‎, ‎end angle=60‎, ‎radius=2cm]‎ -‎-++(60:0.5cm) arc [start angle=60‎, ‎end angle=120‎, ‎radius=2.5cm]‎ -‎-++(120:-0.5cm);‎
    ‎\begin{scope}‎
        ‎\pgfsetfillpattern{dots}{red}‎
        % ‎\fill (120:2.5cm) arc [start angle = 120‎, ‎end angle=60‎, ‎radius=2.5cm] to[out=165,in=10] (90:2.25)to[out=160,in=10] (120:2.5) ;‎
    ‎\end{scope}‎
‎\end{tikzpicture}‎
‎\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure exactly how you want to fill, as your rectangle examples did not fill the full area.

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,patterns,calc}
\usepackage{xparse}
\begin{document}‎
\begin{tikzpicture}  [scale=2]‎
\filldraw [thick,fill=green!20] (120:2cm) arc [start angle = 120, end angle=60, radius=2cm] --++ (60:0.5cm) arc [start angle=60, end angle=120, radius=2.5cm] --++(120:-0.5cm);
\begin{scope}
\pgfsetfillpattern{dots}{red}
  \filldraw (0,2.25)  to [bend right =10]  ((120:2.5cm) arc [start angle = 120, end angle=60, radius=2.5cm]
 to [bend right=10] cycle;
  \filldraw (0,2.25)  to [bend right =20]  ((120:2cm) arc [start angle = 120, end angle=60, radius=2cm]
 to [bend right=20] cycle;
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

(Note I had to remove a lot of unicode RTL control characters before I could run your example)

Comment: Ok, thank you... But this is not my answer....

Comment: @sayros see update (and if that was you with the downvote, why?)

Comment: @ David, ok thank you, the presented answer is right one... Excuse me because of the downvote....